# How to get repository name by Project name in Octopus API?

Tags: azure-devops, octopus-deploy

I want to know the version control repository name by the Project name in Octopus through API. It would be great if u can get the branch name of repo also for the different-2 deployment environments.

And please excuse me, it’s just starting point with Octopus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.  If you only have the name of the project, I recommend using the `/api/[Space-ID]/projects?skip=0&take=100&partialName=[Project Name]` endpoint.  That will return a list of projects that match that partial name.  Generally, the more information provided, the shorter the list to loop through.

The Git repository information is stored in the PersistenceSettings property on the project.

[image: project query results]

If you are looking for the list of branches available to a given project, you can use the `/api/[Space-Id]/projects/[Project-Id]/git/branches` end point.  You can get the Project Id from the ID property on the project object from the above screenshot.

[image: project branches]

You also asked about getting the branch name in a deployment.  The branch is selected when you create a release.

[image: release creation]

You can get a list of releases for a project by visiting the `/api/[Space-ID]/Projects/[Project-Id]/Releases` endpoint.  The list returned is ordered by creation date desc.  The branch used for this particular release was `auto-rollback`.

[image: release object]

To find out the environments the release has been deployed to, you can use the `/api/[Space-Id]/Releases/[Release-Id]/deployments` endpoint.  That will tell you which environments the release has been deployed to along with the status of each deployment.

[image: deployments]

I hope that helps!  If I missed something, let me know and I can amend the answer!

Comment: Thank you Bob, I want to get the branch name of each environment of the project. So for example if a project is deployed on environments like Beta, UAT and Production. Then the API response should have the branch name of the latest release of each environment

Comment: And in next step I need to get machine’s name (on which application is deployed) for each environment for the given project

Comment: @viveknuna You might want to use tenant tags for Beta, UAT and Production.

Comment: @spikey_richie sorry I’m not aware of tenant tag, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Have a look in the octopus documentation

Comment: I am not using Octopus API, I am using the Octopus Client library. So Can you please provide me the answer based on the Octopus Client library?

Comment: @viveknuna In that case, you'll need to raise a support request to Octopus.